# WPF draw Border on MouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, image, border, mouseover

I have a WPF Application where I am trying to make a close button like image.
I am trying to draw a border or have a border show up on mouse over... But I cannot seem to make it work.
I have tried like 6 different methods of doing so...Images, borders with images, brushes, ect.

I am using the following code at the moment:

```
<Canvas Name="cMin" Height="16" Width="16"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="_.png" Stretch="None" />
    </Canvas.Background>
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent" 
            CornerRadius="0" Height="18" Width="18">
         <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightBlue" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>
</Canvas>
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that your local value for the `BorderBrush` property is taking precedence over your `Style` `Trigger`.  [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) describes how the effective value is resolved.  Basically, remove the local value from the `Border` element, and it should work.  If you need to specify the property, you can do so in a `Setter` in the `Style`.  Also, the second `Trigger` is not needed, as the value will revert to the original value when the property switches back to false:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent" 
        CornerRadius="0" Height="18" Width="18">
     <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightBlue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```